# Is it any methods in GWT to get screenshot of page region?

Tags: gwt, canvas, screenshot

I am using GWT. I have a set of dragable widgets that can be placed on page as user wants. I need to get page region screenshot as a handler of some event and save it. Is any way to do this?

Is it possible to get Widget view as an image in GWT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create applet to get screenshots. You can embed the applet in your GWT application/

Comment: What kind of applet? What API should be used?

Comment: Basically you just need a Java screen capture solution wrapped in an applet. Then you can invoke the applet from javascript when a screen capture is required

Answer (score 0):

No. Sorry. You cannot get a screenshot of any page region in any browser, for security reasons.

There is one exception, `drawWindow` which is not part of GWT but part of HTML5 Canvas and only works in firefox, and only locally (not allowed to run on normal webpages).